# How can I make dot folders / files visible in unity?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

I'm using ironpython in unity to run some scripts with some python packages, when running the project I get :

```
OSException: cannot load library C:\Users\Sai\Documents\Work\Unity\Unity-Python-Demo-master\Assets\StreamingAssets\Lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.SVHFG5YE3RK3Z27NVFUDAPL2O3W6IMXW.gfortran-win32.dll
```

problem is that unity hides folders and files that stars with a dot '.'. how can I solve this ? one of the packages require a file that's inside '.lib' folder, but its hidden, and I can only see that folder in explorer window not in the unity project.

here's my code :

```
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath);
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\StreamingAssets" + @"\Lib\");
        searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\StreamingAssets" + @"\Lib\site-packages\");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(Application.dataPath + @"\StreamingAssets" + @"\Python\pt.py");
        test = py.CTScan("Codemaker");
```

as u can see bellow, the ".lib" folder is not visible in the project :

[in the unity project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHXKR.png)
[explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inqml.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Apparently there is no way!**

See [Unity Manual - Special folder names](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html):

> #### Hidden Assets
>
> During the import process, Unity completely ignores the following files and folders in the Assets folder (or a sub-folder within it):
>
> - Hidden folders.
> - Files and folders which start with ‘.’.
> - Files and folders which end with ‘~’.
> - Files and folders named cvs.
> - Files with the extension .tmp.
>
> This is used to prevent importing special and temporary files created by the operating system or other applications.

These files do not make it into the Unity import and thus also not into a build!

---

I guess ways around that would be to

- pre-compile it as a plug-in DLL that internally stores and provides these files and use that instead.
- well, use a different folder name
- find another way of providing the files to your app that is not within the `Assets` folder (e.g. try using the [persistenDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead or e.g. use a zip and decompress it on runtime)

---

Just a general sidenote:

**Do not use string concat (`+ "\"`) for system file paths!**

Rather use directly [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) and more general [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which inserts the correct path separator according to the device's OS e.g. like

```
searchPaths.Add(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Lib", "site-packages"));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
problem is I can't exactly change the folder name nor its location, I didn't provide the folder names of the package, ironpython does this, store these files like that and I have no idea how to do it.